# Operador condicional ?: não esta funcionando

Tags: c, operadores

Não estou conseguindo utilizar o ?:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main()
 {
 int num1 = 10;
 int num2 = 20;
 int resposta;

 num1 < num2 ? printf("sim\n") : printf("nao\n");

 // O erro acontece aqui ao compilar

 num1 < num2 ? resposta = 10 : resposta = -10;

 printf("%i\n", resposta);


 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: O ternário aceita _statements_ quando dentro de `()`: `num1 < num2 ? (resposta = 10) : (resposta = -10);`, mas como no seu caso é fazer uma atribuição de valor, a resposta abaixo é a melhor solução.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O operador condicional só aceita expressões e não *statements*, por isso não funciona. Ambos podem ser melhor escritos usando operador condicional apenas na parte que realmente varia, e que é uma expressão.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int num1 = 10;
    int num2 = 20;
    printf(num1 < num2 ? "sim\n" : "nao\n");
    int resposta = num1 < num2 ? 10 : -10;
    printf("%i\n", resposta);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/nRu7y0). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/oylzrgmk-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Operator/Conditional.c).

Comment: Notei quem o seu algoritmo é mais curto que o meu, ainda nao sei o que pode e o que nao pode, por exemplo nao sabia que poderia usar esse operador "?:" dentro de um "printf", ou até mesmo na mesma linha que a linha de declaração de variavel. me sugere algum livro ou algo to tipo para que eu possa aprofundar o meu conhecimento?

Comment: @GabrieldaSilvaSantos provavelmente porque está aprendendo do jeito errado, como quase todo mundo. A sugestão é aprender os fundamentos antes de aprender a programar. Não gosto muito de sugerir nada porque nem sempre tudo é bom, nem sempre serve para a pessoa, nem sempre a pessoa saberá usar de modo apropriado.

Answer (score 0):

Use o if else normal

```
if(num1 < num2)
    resposta = 10;
else
    resposta = -10;
```

Comment: A sua solução esta boa, mas eu gostaria de saber a utilizar o operador " ?: " pois, é o que eu estava quebrando a cabeça.

Comment: Oi Antony! É sempre bom juntar texto a explicar código, assim fica mais claro para todos como o código funciona

Comment: Tudo bem, Gabriel. Entendi Sérgio. Entrei na comunidade agora, ainda estou aprendendo a como me comportar aqui. Obrigado pela dica!